# Write to file without callback Node js

Tags: node.js

How do you write a `writeFile()` function without a callback?

This does not work:

```js
fs.writeFile("/logs/file.log", 'Message')

fs.writeFile("/logs/file.log", 'Message',null)
```

Both throw a:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function
```

I need to implement a non-blocking solution.

Comment: you should probably utilize the callback in order to verify it worked

Comment: Do you mean `fs.writeFileSync`?

Comment: @kit That function is synchronous. That's blocking other I/O operations.

Comment: So you understand the difference between async and sync functions, then I am confused about this question

Comment: @kit Hehe I know it's weird. But I want to keep my code clean as there's much writing to files already in my script.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
// create a noop - as in "no operation"
const noop = () => {};

// and pass that in
fs.writeFile("filename.txt", "content", noop);
```

If you're bothered by having to pass a callback at all, create another function:

```
const writeFile = (filename, content) => {fs.writeFile(filename, content, () => {}));

// and use it like this
writeFile("filename.txt", "content");
```

Better yet, if you're using NodeJS > v10.0, then use the `fs.promises.writeFile` API:

```
import fs from "fs";

// this returns a Promise
fs.promises.writeFile("filename.txt", "content");

// which you can await in an async function
async main() {
    try {
        await fs.promises.writeFile("filename.txt", "content");
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
}

// or .then and .catch on it.
fs.promises.writeFile("filename.txt", "content")
    .then(() => { /* do something after */ })
    .catch(e => console.error(e));
```

If on Node < v10.0 you can use the `promisify` utility:

```
import { promisify } from "util";
import fs from "fs";

const writeFile = promisify(fs.writeFile);

// this returns a Promise that you can await or .then
await writeFile("filename.txt", "content");
```

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted. Do you think not closing the file is okay? I will be writing one time each second to the file.

Comment: The file is closed right away. If you're doing this in a "fire and forget" manner where you don't care whether the write succeeded or failed, then you're good with this approach. Do test, however, to make sure Node doesn't throw an application level exception and quit unexpectedly if write fails.

Answer (score 4):

> I need to implement a non-blocking solution.

Because of that you must use an **ASYNC** function instead of sync.

`writefile()` is an async function, thus you need a `callback function` for it.

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile("/logs/file.log", "Message", function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }

    console.log("The file is saved!");
    // Here you can write code about what happen next!

});
```

Comment: Okay, you are right. I can use it to close the file at least.

Comment: And this is the best answer in term of how it should be for basic error handling

Comment: @EtienneCha I was asking since in my case I don't care about error handling. It's just a logger function. If it fails, something worse has happened. The function has to run one time each second so I will get millions of "The file is saved"... That's what I don't want.

Comment: All good, just log a message in case of error in a specific file :) and when all green don't log anything.

Answer (score 3):

If you really don't care about the result (error yes/no), this might do the trick.

```
fs.writeFile("/logs/file.log", 'Message', () => {})
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `writeFile`, you can use `writeFileSync` instead. `writeFile` requires the callback to be passed whereas `writeFileSync` doesn't need a callback function. For more info, you can refer to [`writeFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options) NodeJS Docs

This should work for you

```
fs.writeFileSync("/logs/file.log", 'Message')
```

As I read your comment on the question, if you are looking to stick to `writeFile`, you need to pass the callback function as it's async. You can shorten it by writing

```
fs.writeFile("/logs/file.log", 'Message', () => {})
```